# How to align text to right without adding additional vertical spacing?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I am trying to simply align one paragraph to the right. However, when I try to use `flushright` environment, additional vertical space is added above that environment:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ut voluptatem at voluptatibus omnis ratione tenetur. A, voluptates. Enim beatae suscipit nesciunt sunt voluptatem, sit blanditiis nobis accusamus vitae nisi tempora odit eius molestias laborum obcaecati maiores optio placeat aut temporibus alias omnis porro minus ex! Illum dolores, explicabo assumenda?

\begin{flushright}
This text should be aligned to right side with no vertical space above it.
\end{flushright}

Some regular text which should not be affected by above commands.

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, when I try to use `\raggedleft`, no vertical space is added before this paragraph, but all following paragraphs are also aligned right (which is not what I intended):

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ut voluptatem at voluptatibus omnis ratione tenetur. A, voluptates. Enim beatae suscipit nesciunt sunt voluptatem, sit blanditiis nobis accusamus vitae nisi tempora odit eius molestias laborum obcaecati maiores optio placeat aut temporibus alias omnis porro minus ex! Illum dolores, explicabo assumenda?

\raggedleft This text should be aligned to right side with no vertical space above it.

Some regular text which should not be affected by above commands.

\end{document}
```

I am not sure how I can un-align text to default (justify) after using `\raggedleft`.

**Is there any way to align text to right, without adding additional vertical space or affecting all text that follows after that alignment?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{\raggedleft text\dots \par}
```

if you want the paragraph aligned to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  Right-aligned wants \verb|\raggedleft|:\par
  {\raggedleft text \par}
  Left-aligned wants \verb|\raggedright|:\par
  {\raggedright text \par}
\end{document}
```

[image: left-right right-left]

Answer (score 3):

You can keep `\raggedright` in a group, just make sure the end of paragraph is in the group so:

```
 {\raggedright text..... \par}
```

Comment: I have tried keeping this in a group, but I didn't think about adding ``\par`` at the end. I am not sure why it is needed, but it works (with ``\raggedleft`` as @cfr noted).

Comment: @Rafal I think it is because TeX figures out what to do with the paragraph only at the end of that paragraph. So whatever is active when the paragraph ends affects the entire thing. Hence if you say `{\tiny some text}\par some more` you will get a bigger space between the lines than if you say `{\tiny some text\par}some more` because the value of `\baselineskip` depends on its value when `\par` is issued (or you leave a blank line or whatever).

Comment: @Rafal oh right/left oops :-)

Comment: @cfr thanks for the (accurate) second comment (you could just have edited my answer for the first comment:-)

Comment: I would not dare to edit an answer of yours...

Comment: @cfr I don't bite

Comment: @cfr I thought that adding one empty line is enough for LaTeX to end paragraph.

Comment: @Rafal a blank line and `\par` are the same thing, it's often easier to use the `\par` form in macros and the blank line in the document but they both make a `\par` token

Comment: @Rafal You could use a blank line so long as it was still within the group i.e. before the closing `}`.

Comment: Having this new paragraph **before** end of group was what I was missing here. Thanks again to both of you.